# What is Firebase and Legacy iOS means in GTM setup

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am new to [GTM](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/) .

I am making a new account for GTM and got the following screen.

I want to Implement only GTM not GA. I will track events via GTM only.

I am getting this screen is Initial Setup:
[image]

I Have two option two select. Firebase and Legacy (iOS).

I am not able to figure it Out. Please suggest me what to do.

I am not Implementing Firbase at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Firebase option uses Firebase Analytics' events as input to Tag Manager. You can use these events to fire (and modify) Firebase events, Google Analytics, other Google tags, custom tags, and some third party tags. Using this SDK doesn't mean you have to use Firebase features other than Firebase Analytics.

The "Legacy iOS" container is the previous version of the SDK. It supports Google Analytics, Adwords, DoubleClick, and custom tags. The legacy SDK requires more code to setup. In the legacy SDK tags are triggered by calling Google Tag Manager's DataLayer APIs.

Comment: Hi @Eric Burley, 
Can you kindly guide me how can i test GTM in my application?

Comment: If you use the "Legacy iOS" container are you able to use third party tags?